# Using CoffeeScript to Add Field in erb to Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I want to create a form that will add fields dynamically based on buttons the user clicks on. I am able to append raw HTML code, but erb code isn't properly being rendered.

**Coffeescript Code:**

```
field = '<%= hello %>'

$ ->
    $('button').click ->
        $('#tests').html(field)
```

When I click on the button, the entire string <%= hello %> is printed on the page. What do I need to add to ensure that the string I'm passing in is interpreted as erb code? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add .erb to your .coffee file.

So, my_file.js.coffee becomes my_file.js.coffee.erb